# Android Studio бесконечно загружает список устройств

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, device

В списке устройств всё время написано "Loading Devices". Как сделать так, чтобы студия загрузила устройства? Я так даже запустить приложение не могу. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Удачный опыт уже был? У меня такая история появилась после обновления студии - вылечилось очисткой кеша: меню `File` -> `Invalidate Caches...`

Comment: Был. Я пробовал это нажимать, вся Студия с ума сходила. Внизу начинает писать одно, сверху - совсем другое...